# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a non-negative and convergent sequence. What guaranty that $\sum _{n}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please I need some suggestion about the following problem.

Suppose that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence of non-negative terms. What are the suitable condition(s) that can guaranty the convergent of the sequence of partial sums of $a_n$? That is, 
$\sum _{n}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent?

Note: The sequence $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: That is a bit too broad. What kind of condition do you consider suitable?

Comment: See [tests of convergence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).

Comment: $lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = 0 \\$ is the necessary condition for the series to be convergent.

Comment: You want sufficient (guarantee that) condition for convergence. There are not such things. There is a *necessary* condition (that the sequence converges to zero), but that is far from sufficient. There are though sufficient conditions for special sequences...

Comment: @Pritam I have only the convergent of $a_n$, I do not have idea about its limit.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I want sufficient conditions (if any) that can guaranty $\sum_{n}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$ without any knowledge about the limit of $a_n$.

Comment: @Hassan As already written, there do not exist such condition *in a general case*. There are some particular cases where this can't be done, but not in general.

Comment: @Hasan then my friend you can't do much because what I've stated is necessary for the convergence of the series. It doesn't matter that the sequence $a_n$ is convergent, unless the limit is $0$ you can't do much. And there's no sufficient condition that relates the convergence of $\{a_n\}\\$ to the convergence of $\sum a_n$>

Comment: @Pritam I feel that such condition(s) exist in this world, I will continue searching for it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Please provide me with some examples of such particular cases.

Comment: For example: if $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is a convergent **geometric** sequence with quotient $\;q\;$, then the series $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges iff $\;|q|<1\;$ . Or if the sequence if of the form $\;a_n=n^p\;,\;\;p\in\Bbb R\;$ , then the series $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges iff $\;p<-1\;$ ...

Comment: @Hasan I was talking about in general cases. Yeah sure you can continue your search for it, and don't forget to share with me. I'd love to know about it too.

Comment: @DonAntonio I will look closer to these particular cases. Thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio I will look closer to these particular cases. Thank you.

Comment: @Hasan here's another example $a_n =\frac{1}{n^p}$ then the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent iff $p\gt1$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have added additional constraint to the sequence.